# Regular Expression data format "Firstname LastName, PhoneNumber, email"

Tags: php, regex

I have a string that is coming thru form and i don't know how to mach it with a regular expression, data that is being worked with is in format like this:

```
FirstName LastName, PhoneNumber, Emailadress
```

So i want to know what regular expression to use to only match string if it is in this format.

Data is send to a search page via form GET method. I want to check the string with regular expresion and if it mathes proceed with the search page.

Because user can enter different data in search box and it will not always be in this format i want to know how to check if data or string is in format firstname lastname, phone...

here is one example url with the data provided that needs to be checked

```
http://localhost/search.php?q=Martha+Marquez%2C+0637460697%2C+Morbi.quis%40pellentesque.ca
```

and this is raw data from $_GET

```
Martha Marquez, 0637460697, Morbi.quis@pellentesque.ca
```

I'm new to regular expressions.
Thanks in advance

Comment: Why make your users enter such a specific format? Why don't you use three form fields rather?

Comment: I am using typeahead like javascript library and when my users enter name in the search bar it automaticly displays suggestions for them. Suggestions are in that format (firstname lastname, phoneNumber, email) so my users can more easily find what they are looking for.
They can just enter name and press Enter and search but suggestions will be shown and if they select one of suggestions it will send them in that specific format to a serch parse page. Thats why i needed to know if it is in that format or not

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Split on the comma (+ whitespaces) and unpack your values using [**`list()`**](http://php.net/manual/en/function.list.php):

```
<?php
$string = "FirstName LastName, PhoneNumber, Emailadress";
list($name, $phone, $email) = preg_split('~,\s*~', $string);

echo $phone;
?>
```

---

To actually **ensure** that the string is of the given format, you could use

```
^(?P<name>[^,]+),\s*(?P<phone>[^,]+),\s*(?P<email>\S+@\S+)\s*$
```

Broken down this says:

```
^                     # start of the string
(?P<name>[^,]+),\s*   # not a comma, 1+ -> group "name"
(?P<phone>[^,]+),\s*  # not a comma, 1+ -> group "phone"
(?P<email>\S+@\S+)\s* # group "email"
$                     # end of the line
```

---

Which in `PHP` would be:

```
<?php
$string = "Martha Marquez, 0637460697, Morbi.quis@pellentesque.ca";

$regex = '~^(?P<name>[^,]+),\s*(?P<phone>[^,]+),\s*(?P<email>\S+@\S+)\s*$~';

if (preg_match($regex, $string, $match)) {
    print_r($match);
} else {
    echo "Wrong format.";
}
?>
```

Comment: Don't forget to trim each of the value - as it is, Phone Number will be ' PhoneNumber'. But MOST IMPORTANTLY, one should always sanitize their value !! For instance, check that firstname is a string of letters no longer than 100.

Comment: Since the question is about *asserting* the concrete string format, a blind explode is probably not the answer. (`explode` - the bane of PHP.)

Comment: @mario: Having re-read the question, I'd propose a regular expression which kind of asserts `"bla bla bla, bla bla bla, bla@bla"`.